Config weblogic to ignore (do not log) specific error/warning
Is there any chance to config Weblogic (12.2.0.1) to ignore specific error / warning?
There is lot of error ADF_FACES-30188 about element dimension. This error appear if developer use percent in element width or height instead of number. Or, if developer set background color with inlineStyle server return similar error.
So, this error is minor and I would like to avoid server write those error in log (my logs are full of those errors).
Thanks in advance

You can create a log filter. See this documentation for details.
